# Determing the size of an svn repository

Tags: svn

I am considering putting my entire repository on an additional computer. However, this computer has limited space, so I dont want to do it if the repository size is massive. Is there a command to see the size of the repository?

Comment: You mean a command on the client-computer, e.g. using `svn -someOption`?

Comment: @M4N That is what I originally intended, but any other way you can think of will also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check your server configuration (Apache or svnserve) to determine the path on the server to your repository database directory. Once you have that, use whatever tool(s) you would use to check the size of any other directory on the computer - `du` on *NIX, for example.